# Get system region in Safari for iOS

Tags: javascript, ios, reactjs, safari, format

In my web app there is an input for the amount with currency.
I'm using [React Currency Input Field](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-currency-input-field) to format it.

On my phone I have language set to Spanish and region set to Taiwan.
Their decimal separators are comma `,` and dot `.` respectively.

The problem is that iOS displays the numeric keyboard with dot as a separator, while the library expects a comma. In a result it is not possible to insert a separator at all.

Standard keyboard would affect the UX so it is out of the question.

The method `window.navigator.locale` returns language code: es-ES. However, in my case I need to retrieve a device's region.

Is there any method to retrieve system region? If not, shall the web app have region defined as the optional settings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After brainstorming, we concluded that it was impossible to determine system preferences.

We have added an optional separate configuration for language and region so that the user can decide whether to stick with the system configuration or overwrite it.